# remove first two digits of customer_number in impala sql

Tags: sql, cloudera

in Cloudera / impala SQL I need to remove the first to digits of a customer_number, 
I tried the following, but this does not work. Can you please help ?
many thanks

```
CREATE TABLE new
STORED AS PARQUET AS
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE t1.customer_number = RIGHT(t1.customer_number, LEN(t1.customer_number) - 2)
from Old;


customer_number     should become short_cust_no     
33764703        764703      
36764624        764624      
36763795        763795      
37764829        764829      
39766002        766002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impala supports [`substr()`](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html) with two arguments.  You can simply do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(t1.customer_number, 3)
FROM Old t1;
```

EDIT:

I had assume `customer_number` was a string, because the OP uses string functions.

If it is a number, use `mod()`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT MOD(t1.customer_number, 1000000)
FROM Old t1;
```

Note:  The types for the arguments to `mod()` need to be compatible so this might require a `cast()` of some sort.

Comment: I am encountering the following mistake with SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(t1.customer_number, 3)
FROM Old t1;                                                                         AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: substr(DOUBLE, TINYINT).                    Why would that be? What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

If all your customer numbers are 14 characters then I think you should be able to do that with

RIGHT(t1.customer_number, 12)

Answer (score 0):

This addresses the  DOUBLE, TINYINT mistake

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
SUBSTR(cast(t1.customer_number as string), 3,10) 
FROM old;
```